# Nest JS - TypeORM connection persistence problem

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have already prepared everything, but after 1 day, typeorm cuts off my connection to my database because there is a firewall, I tried keepAlive but it didn't work, now I'm thinking of disconnecting and reconnecting every time, how can I solve it?

Do not disconnect my connection, or if it will be disconnected, it must be reconnected.